# GeoReference use wordfile in arcgis

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, geolocation, arcgis

I have a tiff image and have the required information to Geo-reference it on the MAP. which called world file like [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=World_files_for_raster_datasets).

using GMAP.NEt API there are many limited functions not like the java script google map API 3.
So any hope to bind C# windows application and javascript map API ?

on other hand, from the ArcGIS link I can know the (X,Y) for each pixel from the image located at the MAP.
BUT how to do that ? is there any method to do to achieve my goal?

Comment: The question is not clear, especially not the title. Do you want to write an application with c# or javascript for georeferencing a tiff image using the .tfw file?

Comment: exactly, but there is applications for that such as ARCGIS, but I need to use C# for that not really javascript, I see that the map API in javascript is big and have many options not like the GMAP API for C#

Comment: I need to use map API but using C# to do GeoReferencing

Comment: +1 for nice idea. I have not done it myself but I believe that this link will help you. Thanks https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21563/georeferencing-an-image-in-c-with-gdal

Comment: I have already the world file information mean the needed GeoReferencing information, but need to do it

Comment: I think @azmuhak is on the right track. Reading [this page](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) suggests you can use the GDAL tools directly in C#. There is example code for a few workflows [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps), although sadly not for `gdal_translate` which is what you actually want. Also see [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27297/how-to-georeference-using-gdal-tools) which has an example of the parameters for `gdal_translate`.

Comment: mmm dos GDAL mainly work on what is the image info, I mean it generate these info? : corner coordinates,projections, rotation